# MariaDB 10.1.18 - Resetting Auto Increment Column After Reboot

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have 2 live MySQL servers, one running on Linux and another running on Windows.

I have recently setup another MySQL environment on Windows however I am getting this error when inserting data into any of the databases's tables...

```
Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine
```

From what I am reading this is because the MySQL auto increment field is reset after rebooting the server, which it does on this machine. However I am not getting this on my production boxes either Linux or Windows, which are the same version, with many reboots.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `imageId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageUrl` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `imageFileName` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `imageComments` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageAddedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageStatus` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `image_UNIQUE` (`imageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46553/discussion-between-ypercube-and-andrew-h).

Comment: isn't this similar to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199 ? which is fixed in mysql 8.0 not sure if mariadb had an earlier fix though

Comment: @jerichorivera that 8.0 is a development version though.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ this one, also http://mysqlserverteam.com/the-mysql-8-0-0-milestone-release-is-available/

Comment: Bug 199 says that deleting _all_ the rows, then rebooting (or restarting mysqld) will reset autoinc.  It effectively did `SELECT MAX(id) ...` after restart.  Were you deleting all the rows???